# localStorage.setItem not working for toggleButton

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am toggling between a graph and a table view of data. I am using localstorage to save the state. From my console, I can see that dataViewType is not set or saved in my localstorage. I am using vanilla JavaScript, what am I getting wrong or missing?

Update: I can set dataViewType now, but how can I get it/preserve the state on refresh? Code reflects new changes.

```
    const toggleData = () => {
    const data = document.querySelectorAll("button.data");
    const dataTable = document.querySelector(".dataTable");
    const dataGraph = document.querySelector(".dataGraph");
    let dataType = localStorage.getItem("dataViewType");
    if (dataType = "block") {
        if (dataTable.style.display === "block") {
            dataTable.style.display = "none";
            dataGraph.style.display = "block";
            data.forEach(
                (element) => (element.innerText = "View data as Table"),
                localStorage.setItem("dataViewType", "block")

            );
        } else {
            dataGraph.style.display = "none";
            dataTable.style.display = "block";
            data.forEach(
                (element) => (element.innerText = "View data as Graph"),
                localStorage.setItem("dataViewType", "none")
            );
        }
    }
};
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    
        const data = document.querySelectorAll("button.data");
        data.forEach((element) =>
            element.addEventListener("click", (event) => ToggleData()),
        );
    }
```

Comment: I think your logic is flawed ... ToggleData doesn't toggle anything, it displays data depending on the current value ... and the current value is set inside the `View...` functions to be what it currently is ... i.e. there's no logic in your code to ***change*** what value is stored in localStorage - run through it on paper if you don't believe me

Comment: This is even not a toggle.
It is just like if a is true then set a to true.
That does nothing.

Comment: where does the method to set localStorage get called? I don't see it.

Comment: @JaromandaX How can I include a logic to change what is stored? The code I shared is an attempt to save the state:

Comment: Don't post large bits of code in comments. Put it in the question

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay, thanks for the feedback. I have updated my question to reflect what I had shared in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your toggle routine is wrong.
First of all neither of the functions will be executed unless there is somethign already stored under `dataViewType` in localstorage and if there is something stored, the same function will be executed over and over again, because it sets the same value that triggers that function execution...

So what you need need is remove `if (dataType) {` and switch places of other conditions:

```
const Toggledata = () => {
    const dataType = localStorage.getItem("dataViewType");

        if (dataType === "Graph") {
            ViewdataTable();

        } else if (dataType === "Table") {
            ViewdataGraph();

        }
};
```